# HDD partitions stopped mounting at startup

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, automount, ddrescue

Apologies for a basic question about Ubuntu from a novice. My laptop has one SSD, where Ubuntu 16.04LTS is installed, and one HDD. They both have several partitions. Yesterday, I tried to recover files from my old corrupt flash drive mounted as *sdc1*. I used several tools, but I suspect that the crucial thing was the following command:

```
ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb4 logfile
```

After I ran it, one of the HDD partitions appeared to be repartitioned and nautilus started showing boxes with arrows near my HDD partition labels. Now, when I reboot, my HDD partitions do not mount automatically. I only see the empty desktop and can launch only one terminal at a time, as they all flock in the upper-left corner of the desktop and can't be moved from there.

`lsblk` gives the following:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0      0 119.2G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1      0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
sda2   8:2      0     3G  0 part 
sda3   8:3      0  83.9G  0 part 
sda4   8:4      0  31.8G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb    8:16     0 931.5G  0 disk 
sdb1   8:17     0   200G  0 part 
sdb2   8:18     0   500G  0 part 
sdb3   8:19     0   200G  0 part 
sdb4   8:20     0  31.5G  0 part 
sdc    8:32     1  29.1G  0 disk 
sdc1   8:33     1  29.1G  0 part /media/me/TOSHIBA
loop0  7:0      0  81.7M  1 loop /snap/core/4017
loop1  7:1      0  81.6M  1 loop /snap/core/4110
loop2  7:2      0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/core/3887
```

Here *sda* is my SSD and *sdb* is my HDD. As you see, the HDD partitions are not mounted.

Here is `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="0AEC-8283" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="3ae1181e-c506-4254-be93-f8ebb7487763"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="OS" UUID="6810-7989" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="6aefe6a8-9e57-4f58-8fed-e4c87cb0890e"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="UBUNTU" UUID="64ef968d-8488-49b1-8dde-a0829168b76f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b61d10c6-e5a8-456b-bf9c-19bff4b97c66"
/dev/sda4: UUID="181a3feb-93f6-4e98-8583-52a683f658bc" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="e0c61132-4bc0-4089-be6f-e035b89e404a"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="C" UUID="16D1E84B6E1AEFF3" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e1d5874f-01"
/dev/sdb2: LABEL="D" UUID="329D74C657FEB321" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e1d5874f-02"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="F" UUID="4E0068F541357DFD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e1d5874f-03"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="64A7-9503" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e1d5874f-04"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
```

*/dev/sdb4* appears to be repartitioned by `ddrescue`.

Here is `fstab`:

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
/ was on /dev/sda3 during installation  
UUID=64ef968d-8488-49b1-8dde-a0829168b76f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation  
UUID=0AEC-8283  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1  
swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation  
UUID=181a3feb-93f6-4e98-8583-52a683f658bc none            swap    sw              0       0
```

It is easy to fix each time as nautilus still sees my partitions and they mount after I click on their icons.

The only abnormal thing which I see in gparted is the warning mark at */dev/sdb4* saying

> 30.55 GiB of unallocated space within the partition. To grow the file system to fill the partition, select the partition and choose the menu item: Partition->Check"

Besides, this partition is fat32 while the other HDD partitions are ntfs. I don't remember if they were these originally or changed by `ddrescue`.

Now, I think that I can easily fix all this in the sense that I can repartition */dev/sdb4* and edit *fstab*. However, being a novice and not fully understanding what's going on, I would rather prefer to roll all this back to where it was before the corruption.

The `ddrescue` logfile follows:

```
Rescue Logfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.19
Command line: ddrescue -f -r3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb4 logfile
Start time:   2018-03-04 01:39:04
Current time: 2018-03-04 01:41:40
Finished
current_pos  current_status
0x102FBE00     +
      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x102BC000  +
0x102BC000  0x00040000  -
0x102FC000  0x2D100000  +
```

`dmesg` says *EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro*

What exactly could have happened? I think it was more than just repartitioning of */dev/sdb4*. Why are the partitions not auto-mounting now? How can I roll this back? Will everything restore to normal if I do Partition->Check on */dev/sdb4* as gparted suggests?